# Difference between timestamp(0) and timestamp(6)

Tags: timestamp, teradata

Can some body tell me the difference between timestamp(0) and timestamp(6) in Teradata

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`timestamp(p)`, where `p` is the number of digits in the fractional part of second (microseconds), 0 ⇐ p ⇐ 6. With 0 there are no fractions of the second.

- [TIMESTAMP documentation on official Teradata site](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_111A/ch04.043.034.html#ww18262798)

Answer (score 4):

The number (0 or 6) is the number of digits for fractions of a second that you want to store.  6 is the maximum.

- [TIMESTAMP documentation on official Teradata site](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1143_111A/ch04.043.034.html#ww18262798)